# going to a specific html links with mechanize-firefox

Tags: html, perl

its a sample HTML and I want to get links with mechanize-firefox,which is in `<div class="testclass2">` not from others, how can I do it?

```
<div class="testclass1">
    <span class="SelectItem">
        <a class="SelectLink">
            <span class="SelectText">link1</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="testclass2">
    <span class="SelectItem">
        <a class="SelectLink">
            <span class="SelectText">link 1</span>
        </a>
    </span>
    <ul class="SelectList">
        <li class="SelectItem">
            <a class="SelectLink">link 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$mech->xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#mech-xpath-query-options) to do that. All you need to do is build the right xpath expression to get all `a` tags under `class="testclass2"`.

```
my @links = $mech->xpath('//div[@class="testclass2"]//a');
```

The expression is the most tricky thing about it. The `//` means *anywhere under where you are*. This is like `div.testclass2 a` in CSS.